# Codeigniter 3 session error 500

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm having problems with sessions in the CI 3 .

I'm having the "error 500" every time that users login on my website.

In the past I had same problems because I created on login sessions and the cookie size was only 4k. Becouse of this, today I use database to store my sessions and it seems that I still have the cookie size limite problem.

I disable the creation of some sessions ( randomly sessions to make sure the problem is not of specifies session ) and the problem (error 500) stop. When I uncomment all sessions, I get the error 500.

Why this is happening if I use database sessions and the filed are TEXT?

Part of the code:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('l_usr', $user_id);
$this->session->set_userdata('l_usr_email', $user_email);
$this->session->set_userdata('l_usr_login', $user_login);
$this->session->set_userdata('l_nivel', $user_nivelacesso);
$this->session->set_userdata('l_usr_genero', $user_genero);
//$this->session->set_userdata('token', $token_id);
$this->session->set_userdata('l_usr_pic_perfil', "usuarios/".$user_id."/perfil/".$user_foto_perfil);
//$this->session->set_userdata('l_usr_pic_avatar', "usuarios/".$user_id."/perfil/".$user_foto_avatar);
```

Tanks

Comment: Please provide the code, what you have done to solving the problem so far.

Comment: You're going to be much better off just storing just the users id in the session and then using that to query the db to get any further information as and when you need it i.e. creating a user model that will get all the information you need for the user.

Comment: Nucleo, the code is that!! To work, I just comment at minimum 2 sessions. If I uncomment all, I get the error 500

Comment: Ross, tanks for you suggestion!